# Is there something like the 'opposite' of yield?

Tags: c#, yield

I recognize that I cannot hold my complete data in memory, so I want to stream parts in memory and work with them and then write them back.

Yield is a very useful keyword, it saves the whole bunch of using an enumerator and saving the index,....

But when I want to shift `IEnumerable` via yield around and write them back to a collection/file do I need to use the enumerator concept or is there something similar like the opposite of yield? 
I head about RX, but I´m not clear if it solves my problem?

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> ReadFile()
    {
        string line;

        var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\\temp\\test.txt");
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            yield return line;
        }

        reader.Close();
    }

    public static void StreamFile()
    {
        foreach (string line in ReadFile())
        {
            WriteFile(line);
        }
    }

    public static void WriteFile(string line)
    {
        // how to save the state, of observe an collection/stream???
        var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\temp\\test.txt");
        writer.WriteLine(line);

        writer.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your question a bit more? What do you mean by "shift `IEnumerables` around"? `IEnumerable<T>` is lazy evaluated, meaning the method won't even begin executing until you start iterating it.

Comment: I mean, I want to read the data as a block or a stream process them in memory and write them back. Before I read all the data in a datatable, looped over them, converted values, added columns, delted rows,.... and them wrote the complete datatable back (xml, database, csv,...). But the data is too much (the datatables get too big) and I need to split the processing (read, process, write) into 'blocks' or use somthing like streaming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, you can pass the `IEnumerable<string>` directly to WriteFile:

```
public static void WriteFile(IEnumerable<string> lines)
{
    // how to save the state, of observe an collection/stream???
    using(var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\temp\\test.txt"))
    {
        foreach(var line in lines)
            writer.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Since the input is streamed through an `IEnumerable<T>`, the data will never be held in memory.

Note that, in this case, you could just use [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) to perform the read, as it already streams the results back via an `IEnumerable<string>`.  With `File.WriteAllLines`, your code could be done as (though, you could also just use `File.Copy`):

```
File.WriteAllLines(outputFile, File.ReadLines(inputFile));
```

Comment: Thanks, thats usefull! But as I wrote, I ´m not only using files, that was just a sample. I use also XML, ADOAdapter loop through the data and shift them between datatables. Before I wanted to load all data in a datatble, but it was too much, so I try to redesign the application and use 'streaming'. How to use this on other collections or is it a generic solution?

Comment: @JohnnyBravo75 That's why I showed you the first example - you can just push the `IEnumerable<T>` around, since it doesn't actually evaluate until you start enumerating through it.

Comment: @JohnnyBravo75 This is a generic solution - `IEnumerable<T>` will effectively always "stream" results.  Are you looking for something different, or is there a reason you unmarked this?

Comment: No, I got confused, if it really answers my question, but I remarked it because it is fitting. I mean, I want to read data as a block or stream and process it (loop over it and convert) and save the data back to an arbitrary format.

Comment: @JohnnyBravo75 Yes, if you stream the data into an `IEnumerable<T>`, you can loop over it, process, and save the data back one element at a time, without ever loading into memory.  This is what this answer shows.